# help: bash error in emacs rust/cargo

Tags: emacsclient

i get this error in emacs when runing a rust file (have rust and cargo):

```
cargo run 
/bin/bash: cargo: command not found

Compilation exited abnormally with code 127 at Thu Aug  8 20:28:50
```

yet i have cargo  :

```
cargo --version 
cargo 1.36.0 (c4fcfb725 2019-05-15)
```

```
type -a cargo 
cargo is /var/root/.cargo/bin/cargo
```

Comment: Is `cargo` in your `PATH`? How do you expect `bash` to find it?

Comment: Please do not post the same question in SO and in SE.emacs. Please choose one and delete the other.